# Getting a variable inside another variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Ok so I'm getting a php variable and putting it in a javascript variable and that works fine. But now I need to get the output of this var

```
var ltc_cryptsy
```

into

```
var data1 = [{
    field1: 'LTC',
    field2: Here's where I need to put the variable,
    field3: '$601',
    field4: '$599',
    field5: '$605',
    field6: '$597',
    field7: '$599',
    field8: '$605',
    field9: '$597'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Try: `data1[0].field2 = ltc_cryptsy;`

Comment: And did you try just sticking the variable in there to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data1[0].field2=ltc_cryptsy` will work

Comment: Can I just say I love the hell out of you! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: vote up and check the answer if it's able to solve your problem.